# Meaning of "pop style stack without without push" in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

What does it mean when Kivy gives this warning message? What can cause it?

```
[WARNING] [Label       ] pop style stack without push
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any documentation about this message specifically, but here's the relevant bit from the [source code](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-1.10.1/_modules/kivy/core/text/markup.html) that handles BBCode-style text markup:

```
def _pop_style(self, k):
    if k not in self._style_stack or len(self._style_stack[k]) == 0:
        Logger.warning('Label: pop style stack without push')
        return
    v = self._style_stack[k].pop()
    self.options[k] = v
```

The BBCode format lets you, for instance, make a word italic like `[i]this[/i]`. As the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.text.markup.html) puts it:

> A tag is defined as `[tag]`, and should have a corresponding `[/tag]` closing tag.

The wording of the error message is probably not the most user-friendly. It refers to the fact that the tags are handled internally as a stack; an opening tag is pushed onto the stack, and a closing tag is popped off of it. The error means you're trying to pop a style that's not already pushed onto the stack—in other words, you've closed a tag that's not already open.

Comment: This was it. I identified the extra open tags and the warnings went away.